# Blender not working with Python

Tags: blender, blender-2.50

I'm trying to run an external script with blender 2.49b and 2.57

I tried with installing Python versions, 2.4, 2.6 and 2.7.

I'm getting this error in the console window.
Anyone have a clue of what I'm missing?

**Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in    File "C:\Program Files\Blender
2.49b.blender\scripts\blended_cities_24hook.py ", line 77, in 
    from random import randint,random,uniform   File "C:\Python24\LIB\random.py", line 41, in 
    from warnings import warn as _warn   File "C:\Python24\LIB\warnings.py", line 258, in 
    simplefilter("ignore", category=OverflowWarning, append=1) NameError: name 'OverflowWarning' is not defined**

Computer Info:
Operating Sys: Win7 x64.
CPU: Intel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it! In my sys vars, I had the Python path set to the 2.4 version, which doesn't work with these versions of blender.